# JavaMail - inlined images are also being attached to the email

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

I have added inline images in my mail but it's getting attached with mail as well. My code:

```
public Map<String, String> sendMail(final String campaignId, final String emailTo[], final String emailSubject, final String emailBody, final MultipartFile[] mailAttachment) {

    Map<String, String> messageMailIdMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    SMTPMessage SMTPMessageArray[] = new SMTPMessage[emailTo.length];
    try {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        messageHelper.getMimeMessage().setHeader("X-Priority", "High");
        messageHelper.getMimeMessage().setHeader("Return-Receipt-To", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailId());
        messageHelper.getMimeMessage().setHeader("Disposition-Notification-To", AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailId());
        messageHelper.setFrom(AppProperties.getInstance().getEmailId(), AppProperties.getInstance().getUserNameAlias());
        messageHelper.setSubject(emailSubject);

        if (mailAttachment != null)
            for (final MultipartFile multipartFile : mailAttachment) {
                if (multipartFile.getSize() != 0) {
                    String attachName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();

                    messageHelper.addAttachment(attachName, new InputStreamSource() {

                        @Override
                        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                            return multipartFile.getInputStream();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        for (int i = 0; i < emailTo.length; i++) {
            messageHelper.setTo(emailTo[i]);

            if (emailBody != null && emailBody.contains("<img")) {
                UtilityClass.saveEmailInlineImagesInTemp(emailBody);
                messageHelper.setText(UtilityClass.appendUnsubcribeTextUrl(UtilityClass.setInlineTextWithImages(emailBody),unsubcribeTextUrl(emailTo[i],campaignId)), true);

                int occurance = StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(emailBody, "<img");
                for (int j = 0; j < occurance; j++) {
                    File inlineImage = new File(UtilityClass.mailTempFolderPath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + j + "mailInlineImage.png");
                    messageHelper.addInline(j + "mailInlineImage", inlineImage);
                }
            } else
                messageHelper.setText(UtilityClass.appendUnsubcribeTextUrl(emailBody.toString(),unsubcribeTextUrl(emailTo[i],campaignId)), true);// //Mail
            messageHelper.getMimeMessage().saveChanges();

            messageMailIdMap.put(emailTo[i], messageHelper.getMimeMessage().getMessageID());

            SMTPMessage smtpMessage = new SMTPMessage(messageHelper.getMimeMessage());
            smtpMessage.setReturnOption(SMTPMessage.RETURN_FULL);
            smtpMessage.setNotifyOptions(SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_DELAY | SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_FAILURE | SMTPMessage.NOTIFY_SUCCESS);
            SMTPMessageArray[i] = smtpMessage;
        }

        mailSender.send(SMTPMessageArray);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Sending!!!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        File mailTempFolder = new File(UtilityClass.mailTempFolderPath());
        if (mailTempFolder.exists()) {
            for (File file : mailTempFolder.listFiles())
                file.delete();
            System.out.println("tempFilesDeleted........");
        }
    }

    return messageMailIdMap;
}
```

`UtilityClass.saveEmailInlineImagesInTemp(emailBody)` collects image info from html img tag and creates an image files.

`UtilityClass.setInlineTextWithImages(emailBody)` creates message body with img tags like `<img src="cid:0mailInlineImage">`

`messageHelper.addInline(j + "mailInlineImage", inlineImage);` adds inline images

`SMTPMessageArray[i] = smtpMessage;` to create an array of mails to send to multiple recipients with same session. I'm using Spring JavaMailSender to create MimeMessage.

Log from `System.out`:

```
From: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
To: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Message-ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Subject: bellaward
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_16_711673112.1452149784499"
X-Priority: High
Return-Receipt-To: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Disposition-Notification-To: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

------=_Part_16_711673112.1452149784499
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
    boundary="----=_Part_17_1410900889.1452149784499"

------=_Part_17_1410900889.1452149784499
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hi </p><p>How Are you</p><p><br></p><p><img src='cid:0mailInlineImage'></p><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>Thanks<br></p>
------=_Part_17_1410900889.1452149784499
Content-Type: image/x-png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-ID: <0mailInlineImage>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAACvCAIAAAADl5AeAAB0yUlEQVR42uy9h39c1bX3/fwnz+d9
npvgIttyg5Qnt+Tm3hBIw8aqM2ouQAgBLsm9SSCh2OqSMSWFjrFVpo96l1yxZbXpfdR718yc3t61
zpEnwtYYy0iWDDP8PkIanzlzzj77u9dae6+99//aU9QUV1xxPaD6X/EiiCuuOMBNuwsb44orrvus9++rAvgbIf8f/DPHTHrGDe4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
------=_Part_17_1410900889.1452149784499--

------=_Part_16_711673112.1452149784499--
```

Comment: kindly elaborate more your question

Comment: Show us some code and the mime structure of your emails

Comment: i have edited my question please help

Comment: Could you also add how a message looks like with smtpMessage.writeTo (System.out); ?

Comment: see edit base 64 code was very big so i trimmed it

Comment: MimeMessageHelper seems to be creating a top level multipart/mixed part that's completely unnecessary in this case.  Since that top level multipart has only one part (the multipart/related), it's probably confusing your mail reader, which is displaying the "related" image (which isn't really the same as "inline") as if it were an attachment.  What mail reader are you using to view the message?  If you add a plain text attachment to the message, does it display two attachments for your message?

Comment: I am using Outlook to view these mails . I am not sending any attachment, the images are inline but getting attached as well, so should I change in content type header? Should I check it with other mail viewer or its a code issue.